# JSON view (rest export)

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I have a rest export view and this is my output:

```
{
  title: "about",
  view: "[{"id":7,"field_history_json":7,"field_history_text":"sdfsfsdffd","field_history_year":3244}]"
}
```

My field "view" is a string and I need this to be an object/array, like this.

```
{
  title: "about testes",
  view: [
    {
      id: 1,
      field_history_json: 1,
      field_history_text: "sdsdfsfsfd",
      field_history_year: 234
    }
  ]
}
```

Like I said I have a rest export view of "About" content type.
"About" content type has a paragraph field.
Paragraph field has 3 fields (text, year and file).

I also have a rest export nested view, this view has paragrpah fields that I want to display.

I import paragraph view (rest export nested view) to my first view ("About") and display it with "Views field view" module.

That's how I am getting output as string.

Is there a way to convert string to JSON object in Drupal 8?

Comment: Look into creating your own Normalizer class. It will allow you to create the response shape you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kevin

I will search more about that. If you know any good tutorial/explain how to do it step by step let me know please.
I'm new at JSON and Normalizer class.

Comment: Serialization API doc page: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/serialization-api/serialization-api-overview

Blog post on using normalizers to alter data: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/using-normalizers-alter-rest-json-structure-drupal-8/